# Issue with running parent jQuery function from iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Running into an issue here. I have an iFrame that on click needs to open up another page within a separate iframe on the same parent page (two iframes on a single parent page on frame 1 links open in frame 2). The UX function requires that the second iframe fade in from hiding. We are able to get the frame to load but the problem is that the `.fadeIn` does not work with `.click()`.

jQuery Code on iframe 1:

```
$(".frame-link").click(function() {
  $('#node-frame', window.parent.document).fadeIn();
});
```

It works fine without the click function if the iframe 1 script is simply:

```
$('#node-frame', window.parent.document).fadeIn();
```

When we attempt to do an on click command no luck. Anyone know what we might be missing?

**Note:**
`#node-frame` css set to hidden on parent css

Comment: By default the iframe is a `special` element. Try to set the `seamless` attribute to it. Then it will behave as a normal page element.

Comment: Added it but still no luck. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Could you please explain more explicitly what you want?

Comment: @DhruvRamani Ramani Why the above jQuery code in frame 1 is not working.

Comment: So you mean like when you dont have the click event on .frame-link and you want the fadeIn to workd?

Comment: @DhruvRamani no the other way around. .frame-link on click should execute the fadeIn. the .frame-link is in the iframe and the div on for the fadeIn is on the parent. Somehow the .click does not work.